# Is it possible to prevent a breakpoint highlighting the entire anonymous function?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This is in VS 2015 Professional.

I often use code like the following, when calling a function that accepts a `Func` or `Action` as a parameter:

```
DoAction(()=>
{
    int x = GetInt();

    int y = DoCalculations(x);

    Console.WriteLine(y);
});
```

VS allows me to add a breakpoint on the DoAction line, but as the anonymous function is technically a single parameter, all of the above gets highlighted in the breakpoint colours. As a result, if I also want to add a breakpoint inside the anonymous function it becomes difficult to see.

Is there a setting in Visual Studio that would prevent the entire anonymous function being highlighted when a breakpoint is set on the calling line, or a way to make it easier to see if there is also a breakpoint inside?

Currently the only way to tell is the circle at the left of the editor.

Comment: There are two options for breakpoint visibility in Visual Studio. With option 1, you get the red circle in the editor margin. With option 2, you get the background of the affected line(s) filled with red.

Comment: @CodyGray: I've not found that option anywhere, but it doesn't seem helpful in this case. What I'm looking for is a way to highlight the line, except for the inside of an anonymous function or a way to make it easily visible when one breakpoint is inside another.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to do that. The editor interface still treats breakpoints as line-level items, like they have been since the early days of Microsoft C. The debugger actually supports inserting breakpoints at a finer-grained level than that, like inside of a lambda, but you aren't going to see this in the IDE. Use the Breakpoints window (Ctrl+Alt+B) to see everything at a glance.